# Redirect loop in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, loops

why is this causing a redirect loop? How do I have to change the code, to make it work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com/?___store=german
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com/?___store=dutch
```

Thank you,

Toby

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}         !\b___store=\w+\b
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$                      /?___store=german   [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}         !\b___store=\w+\b
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$                      /?___store=dutch    [L,QSA]
```

You don't need the `http://website.com`.  `.htaccess` files loop so adding [L] isn't good enough; you need to detect the loop and looking for the store parameter is a good way.  You also need the [QSA] flag if some requests use additional params.

Comment: Ok great, seems to work! Thanks a lot! :)
I´m just not sure what happens if the visit is another language, which version does he get? Standard should be nl. Thanks.

Comment: I think there is still a bug in it, now it´s always the de-version loading. When I switch the preferred browser-language to NL, still the DE-version loads.

Comment: The Accept-Language header is a list.  I don't know how yours is set up.  Do a phpinfo() script and look for HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE; It may be that order is important.  E.g. `nl,de` will give the symptoms that you suggest.  You could try `^de` and `^nl` as the match strings, but this you fail on `fr,de`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^___store [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com/?___store=german [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^___store [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com/?___store=dutch [L]
```

If you go to website.com with AL of 'de', and then you get redirected to __store=german, your AL will still be 'de', so it will keep trying to redirect to that __store=german. Adding the `[L]` flag will stop apache from attempting to redirect multiple times.

This is another option, although the ___store parameter would have to be the same as the accept language. I think this should work (not exactly sure on the specifics of passing variables from a condition)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (de|nl) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^___store [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com/?___store=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but it´s still not working. It´s still looping.

Comment: The request will still get redirected (because of the `http://`) and **Accept-Langage** gets matched again, which will redirect again, which will match again, etc., etc.

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought it would have stopped at that LAST rule, and not tried to rewrite it again. Updated my answer, though lol - totally didn't notice the other reply.. heh. wasnt there before o_o